# Show that a set is nowhere dense in C[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

Show that for any $x_0\in[0,1]$ and $y_0\in \mathbb{R}$, $C_{x_0,y_0}=\{f\in C[0,1]:f(x_0)=y_0\}$ is nowhere dense in $C[0,1]$.

So far I have been able to prove the set is closed, but how should I prove it has empty interior? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi! Just so you know - the reason the question is being downvoted is that this site does not consider itself a homework site. People will be happy to help, but you should show context, effort, etc. Best wishes

Comment: @peterag Thank you so much for the notes! I've already modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

try to assume a point in it's interior and assume an open ball around it. you can simply find a function in that ball, which is not in $C_{x_0,y_0}$, and therefor a contradiction. that function can have something like $f(x_0)=y_0 + \epsilon/2$. I hope you can get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much AmirAli! Yes I get the idea, but I was just not so sure about how to phrase it. Still thank you so much for the idea!